# Porque cuando agrego AddBody en RestSharp no envia el request?

Tags: c#, api, post, restsharp, body

reformulo la pregunta que tenia antes.

Tengo la situación en la que estoy intentando hacer un Post a una API propia desde C# con RestSharp.

El problema que tengo es que si yo al request le agrego un body de esta forma

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

o de la siguiente

```
request.AddBody(body);
```

o de la siguiente

```
request.AddJsonBody(body);
```

siempre obtengo como resultado que la petición nunca llega a destino y termina dándome un error por el TimeOut diciendo que "Se excedió el tiempo de la operación".

Pero si yo no agrego ninguna de esas líneas de código, y mando el request sin Body, obtengo la respuesta de la API informándome que falta el body.

El codigo completo del Post es el siguiente:

```
public IRestResponse Post(string resource, Object body)
    {
        try
        {
            

            var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.POST);
            
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddJsonBody(body);
            request.Timeout = 5000;
            
            var response = ExecuteRequest(request);

            return response;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Ojala alguien pueda ayudarme con alguna idea de por donde puede venir el problema con ese body, muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Puedes acceder al destino? A veces hay un firewall que está bloqueando actividad "sospechosa".

Comment: Es que si hago el POST desde Postman por ejemplo, si funciona...

Comment: Antes de jugar a la entrevista/detectives, aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Especialmente el punto 4. Agrega todos los datos para reproducir tu escenario. Saludos